# How to set Radiobutton's text below image in Java

Tags: java, android

My question is fairly simple. I currently have Radiobuttons that look like this :
[image]

I would like to set the text to be below the image (and eventually set it as bold when the button is clicked).

My XML file looks like this :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And part of my Java code :

```
RadioGroup categoryGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_category);

        for(int i=0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
            final String name = categories.get(i).name;
            final int resource = categories.get(i).resource;

            final RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getContext());
            button.setButtonDrawable(resource);
            button.setText(name);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Set text as bold (I'll add some logic too)
                }
            });

            categoryGroup.addView(button);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RadioGroup categoryGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_category);

        for(int i=0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
            final String name = categories.get(i).name;
            final int resource = categories.get(i).resource;

            final RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getContext());
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resource);
            button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable, null, null);
            button.setButtonDrawable(null);
            button.setText(name);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>"+button.getText().toString()+"</h2>",
                                Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    } else {
                        button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>"+button.getText().toString()+"</h2>"));
                    }
                }
            });

            categoryGroup.addView(button);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout linearLayout;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);

    for (int i = 0; i<5 ;i++){
        radioButton = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
        radioButton.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }



    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.setMargins(3, 0, 3, 5);
    getWindow().addContentView(linearLayout, params1);


  }
}
```

This worked for me check this out

this is how it looks.
[image]

Comment: I need to add multiple buttons in Java, or I would have done this in XML

Comment: Edited my answer check this out